# How bind works with new and instanceof?

Tags: javascript, bind, new-operator, instanceof

I had an interview yesterday and there was a task to write JavaScript class that can be created with multiple new and created object has to be instance of all its parents. I tried to do it using Function.bind() but it didnt work.

```js
function JSObject() {
  return JSObject.bind(null);
}

var obj1 = new JSObject();
var obj2 = new obj1();
var obj3 = new obj2();

console.log(obj2 instanceof obj1); // prints false, expected true
console.log(obj3 instanceof obj2); // prints false, expected true
console.log(obj3 instanceof obj1); // prints false, expected true

console.log(obj1 instanceof obj2); // prints false, expected false 
console.log(obj1 instanceof obj3); // prints false, expected false

let objects = [JSObject, new JSObject()];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  objects.push(new objects[objects.length - 1]());
}

for (let obj of objects) {
  const objProt = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  const objProtProt = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj.prototype);
  const funcProt = Object.getPrototypeOf(Function);
  const funcProtProt = Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype);
  console.log(objProt === funcProt); // expected true
  console.log(objProtProt === funcProtProt); // expected true
}
```

In addition I cant change prototype directly, tests have check that prototype of Object has to be Function

Comment: Not sure what exactly the goal is here. Your constructor is always just returning a new function which is itself not a constructor (it's the intermediate function `bind` returns, it's not `JSObject`), though it will return a new instance when called, so it'll never be an instance of anything.

Comment: return _this_ or nothing in a consturcutor in order to get inheritance. You also have to return an object, but that's secondary to your non-this return...

Comment: @dandavis if you return `this` how would you use that as a constructor when you try to call `new obj1();`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer: since only objects may formally come from constructors, you can't return a constructor from a constructor, you would have to use a factory pattern.

Comment: @dandavis That's right, so returning `this` won't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: yeah, i'm just giving some background since it's unclear what OP needs to do here; he says `console.log(obj2 instanceof obj1);` should be both false and true, which is impossible...

Comment: Yes, that looks like a typo. The second one is probably supposed to be `obj2 instanceof obj3`

Comment: @dandavis fixed

Comment: What do you mean by "*can be created with multiple new*"? Also it's unclear what "*instance of all its parents*" is supposed to mean in that context. Were you supposed to make a simple class hierarchy?

Comment: @Bergi the first one means: var obj = new new new new new JSObject();
I think I need to create new objects in such way that it inherits from previous object or root.

Comment: @GrigoryZaripov Yes, looks like that (see my answer). But that also means that each created object is a ("constructor") function, does that conflict with the requirement "*I cant change prototype directly, tests have check that prototype of Object has to be Function*"?

Comment: @Bergi yes, it does. console.log prints expexted values but prototype is changed.

Comment: @gzaripov Can you add that check to the question, please? But I doubt it is possible to have an `obj2` that can both be used with `new` (which requires a function) and can be an instance of `obj1` (which requires it to inherit from `obj1.prototype`) without changing the function's prototype.

Comment: @Bergi added check.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a "class", since you cannot distinguish between a constructor and an instance. Every "constructor" function just creates new objects that are themselves "subclasses".

```
function inherit(parent) {
    function object() {
        return Object.setPrototypeOf(inherit(object), object.prototype);
    }
    object.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    return object;
}
var JSObject = inherit(Function);
```

Or using ES6:

```
function inherit(parent) {
    return class object extends parent {
        constructor() {
            return Object.setPrototypeOf(inherit(object), new.target.prototype);
        }
    }
}
const JsObject = inherit(Function);
```

These even achieve `obj instanceof Function` and `obj.prototype instanceof Function` (and `instanceof Object`, of course). Your additional requirements of `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) == Function.prototype` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj.prototype) == Object.prototype` are not achievable. (Assuming we don't use stateful proxies that cheat your tests).